# Pandas Multiple DataFrames from other DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a base "test" dataframe of varying length, which I am constructing based off of a slider date selector.

```
            seasons
test    
2018-02-19  Winter
2018-02-20  Winter
2018-02-21  Winter
2018-02-22  Winter
... ...
2019-06-25  Summer
2019-06-26  Summer
2019-06-27  Summer
2019-06-28  Summer
```

suppose now that I have multiple dataframes for product prices at different supermarkets like:

```
Loblaws

     Summer   Winter
Milk  -7800.0  -3600.0
Salt  -9000.0  -4500.0
Pear -15300.0 -11700.0

Wal-Mart

     Summer   Winter
Milk -14700.0 -10200.0
Salt  -7500.0  -4800.0
Pear  -3000.0  -9600.0

Whole Foods

     Summer  Winter
Milk -11500.0 -7500.0
Salt  -7000.0 -8500.0
Pear  -1000.0 -6500.0
```

How would I go about making new dataframes with columns based on the items for each supermarket? So for example:

```
Loblaws     seasons Milk    Salt    Pear
2018-02-19  Winter  -3600.0 -4500.0 -11700.0
2018-02-20  Winter  -3600.0 -4500.0 -11700.0
... ...
2019-06-25  Summer  -7800.0 -9000.0 -15300.0
2019-06-26  Summer  -7800.0 -9000.0 -15300.0
```

and the same for Wal-Mart/Whole Foods?

I don't know if it would be better for me to convert the supermarket dataframes to dictionaries and then run in a loop based off of the dictionaries, or if I (join?) them and loop through the supermarket dataframes. Thank you for any and all help.

EDIT: I have been able to do it with a single one, I am just not sure how to do it in an iterative manner (for however many dataframes I have without directly calling them individually). To do one I used:

```
Loblaws = Loblaws.transpose()
Loblaws_Merged = pd.merge(test, Loblaws, left_on='seasons', right_index = True)
```

Comment: tranpose your product price dataframe and merge on the season with the test dataframe ?

Comment: @Mayeulsgc that's very clever, i didn't think of that. I'm not sure what the operation would be; it wouldn't be wide to long, right? Is there specific transpose function in pandas or something similar? Edit: wow, looks like there is a function called exactly transpose haha. I will give this a try and see if I can figure it out

Comment: @Mayeulsgc i managed to do it on a single one of the dataframes just fine. What I can't figure out how to do is do it in an iterative manner (for each)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of @Mayeul sgc's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609931/pandas-multiple-dataframes-from-other-dataframes#comment103531784_58609931) for a multiple case scenario and for the benefit of anyone looking for an answer to the same question: 
you can do the following:

```
merged_dataframes = []
# first put all dataframes in a list
supermarkets = [loblaws, wal_mart, whole_foods]
# then use a for loop and Mayeul sgc's clever code:
for df in supermarkets:
    df = df.transpose()
    merged_dataframe = pd.merge(test, df, left_on='seasons', right_index = True)
    merged_dataframes.append(merged_dataframe)
```

Hope this works for you. Let me know if you needed something else.

Comment: This might be a really dumb question, but I've always wondered about the use of the for *x* in *y*. Does the name of *x* actually matter? If I were to say "for supermarket in supermarkets", would that affect the outcome?

Comment: @poorpractice You are correct, the name x does not matter at all. It's just a variable name. In fact, it would be better (from a readability standpoint) to use `for supermarket in supermarkets`

Comment: @poorpractice, Thanks. Happy coding :)

Comment: @ElegantCode sorry if I may, one more question. i'm trying to assign a name variable to the dataframes in the loop using the .name property, but when I call it outside of the loop and tell it to print the name (or even inside the loop) it instead prints out the pre-merged dataframe for each supermarket. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @poorpractice, No problem, that's what we're all here for... I'm just not sure what you mean by "prints out the pre-merged dataframe". Can you please show your code and output in the comments here?

Comment: not sure how to properly format code in the comments but what i did is:
added: `merged_dataframe.name = str(df)` as a line to your code loop and then try to get the names with:
 `for df in merged_dataframes: 
print(df.name)`

what i get instead is the supermarket dataframes output as they were before they were merged

Comment: @poorpractice, I suspect that you are making the changes to a copy, rather than the original and than perhaps losing the copy and when checking the original, it seems unchanged. But I'm not sure. I suggest that you post your code in a new question, and then post the link to this question right here. No need to explain too much. I'll know what you're talking about and answer it there. Just remember to post the link to it here.

Comment: @poorpractice, It's possible that if you put your `merged_dataframe.name = str(df)` before my `merged_dataframes.append(merged_dataframe)` it will solve your problem. But to be sure I'd have to see your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201568/discussion-between-elegant-code-and-poorpractice).