# Iterative Creation and Naming of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Posting in continuation of [Pandas Multiple DataFrames from other DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609931/pandas-multiple-dataframes-from-other-dataframes/58612808?noredirect=1#comment103540713_58612808[Text]).

Managed to iterate over multiple smaller dataframes (please note that the supermarket names have been added manually to aid in the understanding of the question; the dataframe names do not exist as a property of the dataframes):

```
    Loblaws

     Summer   Winter
Milk  -7800.0  -3600.0
Salt  -9000.0  -4500.0
Pear -15300.0 -11700.0

Wal-Mart

     Summer   Winter
Milk -14700.0 -10200.0
Salt  -7500.0  -4800.0
Pear  -3000.0  -9600.0

Whole Foods

     Summer  Winter
Milk -11500.0 -7500.0
Salt  -7000.0 -8500.0
Pear  -1000.0 -6500.0
```

and merge with the "base" dataframe on "Seasons":

```
for df in locationlist:
    df = df.transpose()
    merged_dataframe = pd.merge(dfs, df, left_on='Season',right_index = True)
    merged_dataframe.name = str(df)
    merged_dataframes.append(merged_dataframe)
    display(merged_dataframe)
```

by transposing such that the output looks like:

```
            Season  Milk    Salt    Pear
Date                
2018-01-24  Winter  -7500.0 -8500.0 -6500.0
2018-01-25  Winter  -7500.0 -8500.0 -6500.0
2018-01-26  Winter  -7500.0 -8500.0 -6500.0
2018-01-27  Winter  -7500.0 -8500.0 -6500.0
2018-01-28  Winter  -7500.0 -8500.0 -6500.0
...         ...     ...     ...     ...
```

However, trying to return the name as a property using:

```
for dfs in merged_dataframes:
    print(dfs.name)
```

prints out the individual dataframes for each supermarket in their pre-merged format like:

```
       Milk     Salt     Pear
Summer -7800.0  -9000.0  -15300.0
Winter -3600.0  -4500.0  -11700.0
       Milk     Salt     Pear
Summer -14700.0 -7500.0  -3000.0
Winter -10200.0 -4800.0  -9600.0
       Milk     Salt     Pear
Summer -11500.0 -7000.0 -1000.0
Winter  -7500.0 -8500.0 -6500.0
```

Comment: `pd.concat(merged_dataframes)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...continuing from the previous question...
I see what's happening here:
when you do `merged_dataframe.name = str(df)` you seem to want the name of the variable from which the dataframe came, 
What actually happens is that you take the whole dataframe that df refers to (an original supermarket dataframe) and turn it all into a string (using the str method), and assign that whole dataframe as the name.

Once you actually print the names you get the name, which is the whole dataframe…

I have good news and bad news:

The bad news: You cannot recover the name of the variable that referred to the dataframe originally, when you wrote this line: `supermarkets = [loblaws, wal_mart, whole_foods]` That variable name is not accessible from within the loop.

The good news: You can work around this by assigning a name variable to the original dataframes by doing something like this before the for loop:

```
merged_dataframes = []
# first put all dataframes in a list
Loblaws.name = "Loblaws"
Wal_Mart.name = "Wal-Mart"
Whole_foods.name = "Whole Foods"
supermarkets = [loblaws, wal_mart, whole_foods]

for df in locationlist:
    name_str = df.name
    df = df.transpose()
    merged_dataframe = pd.merge(dfs, df, left_on='Season',right_index = True)
    merged_dataframe.name = name_str
    merged_dataframes.append(merged_dataframe)
```

I hope this works for you! Let me know how it goes!

Comment: @poorpractice, I added the fix from the chat.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

columns = ['summer','winter']
index = ['milk','salt','pear']
dfs = {
    'Loblaws': pd.DataFrame([[-7800.0,-3600.0],[-9000.0,-4500.0],[-15300.0,-11700.0]], columns=columns, index=index),
    'Wal-Mart': pd.DataFrame([[-14700.0,-10200.0],[-7500.0,-4800.0],[-3000.0,-9600.0]], columns=columns, index=index),
    'Whole Foods': pd.DataFrame([[-11500.0,-7500.0],[-7000.0,-8500.0],[-1000.0,-6500.0]], columns=columns, index=index)
}

for df in dfs:
    dfs[df] = dfs[df].transpose()
    dfs[df]['season'] = dfs[df].index
    dfs[df]['name'] = [df for _ in range(len(dfs[df]))]
    dfs[df].reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

merged_df = pd.concat(dfs.values(), axis=0)
merged_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```